# Adding a pd.Series (with zero NaNs) to a pd.DataFrame is resulting in some NaNs in the added column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

When I add a series that has zero NaNs to a pandas `DataFrame`, the column added is filled with some NaNs.

`pd.Series` that I am trying to add:

[image: pd.Series that I am trying to add]

When I add it to a pandas `DataFrame`, the result is like:

*Before the addition of column:*
[image: Before the addition of column]

*After the addition of column:*

[image: After the addition of column]

The length of both dataframe and series are same.

Why is this the case, and how to resolve this issue?

I tried to use `.loc` instead of regular indexing but still the problem is not resolved. I would like to know a way to add the new column into the existing dataframe without any NaNs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for missing values are different index values in `Series` and `Dataframe`, for prevent it convert `Series` to numpy array:

```
df['fruitsNseeds'] = transformed.to_numpy()
```

If `train_x` is `Series` first convert it to `DataFrame`:

```
df = train_x.to_frame('col')
df['new'] = transformed.to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thanks, but why is it giving NaN? So weird.

Comment: @VasudevaKilaru - Because alignment - it means pandas try assign values by index values and if different, pandas create missing values (cannot find index, so for all not found indices set NaNs)